# How to add suite or apartment number to location in Calendar

Tags: macos, ios, calendar, ical

How can the suite number, apartment number, etc. be added to the location in Calendar on MacOS and iOS?

If an address is typed locations are suggested and Time to Leave alerts are enabled, but as soon as the address is modified Calendar no longer recognizes it as a valid address.

**No Suite:**
[image: No suite]

**With Suite:**
[image: With suite]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entering the suite or apartment number on a separate line with a ***trailing comma***, the address will display on the map as valid.

The Suite number can even be on the same line as the city and it will work but that just looks odd.

To add a new line use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>

[image: Event address with suite number]

Comment: Note that this only seems to work with the comma after the apartment or suite number