# How do you add a suite or apartment number to a location in Calendar?

Tags: macos, mojave, calendar, ical

How can the suite number, apartment number, etc. be added to the location in Calendar on MacOS? I'm using Mojave v10.14.3.

This was supposedly answered in a [Previous Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296776/how-to-add-suite-or-apartment-number-to-location-in-calendar) but that answer isn't working for me and I'm not sure why. I've tried using a trailing comma, and using (control) + (return) on lines instead of just a regular return.

Here is the suggested address WITHOUT a suite number. The location is recognized and a map is populated.

[image: Here is the suggested address WITHOUT a suite number. The location is recognized and a map is populated.]

Here is the same address WITH a suite number on the second line and a trailing comma. I've also tried it on the same line, but either way the location is not recognized and no map is populated.

[image: Here is the same address WITH a suite number on the second line and a trailing comma. I've also tried it on the same line, but either way the location is not recognized and no map is populated.]

Comment: Is it a US convention to put the apartment number after the street address? To me as a Brit, I'd expect to see Suite 404, 2625 West Alameda Ave... Additionally, the first address is W Alameda, rather than West Alameda - maybe it reads it differently

Comment: Generally in the us an Apt. number  (or suite number) **IS** generally put after the street address.

Answer (score 2):

I also attempted to use the trailing comma approach, with no success. However, if you use the field called add Notes, URL or attachment, you can type in an apartment or suite number, and it will not depopulate the map. It's not elegant or ideal, but it doesn't wipe out your ability to get directions from an iPhone

Comment: Yes, I guess that’s the only option. Just seems like a flaw I wish they would correct.

Comment: Another work around seems to be if you add the address to contacts with the apt number and then use the contact to auto fill the address it keeps the apt along with the map.